# How to identify from poles and zeros if it is a bandpass

Tags: matlab, filters, bandpass, poles-zeros

For an example, this is a figure I made from MATLAB, based on the poles and zeros, how can identify if it is a bandpass filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints

1. where are all zero locations?
2. What's the value of the transfer at a frequency that falls directly on a zero?
3. Combine 1 and 2